# How to group records and then select distinct records based on column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to group some records by category and then select all distinct/unique records based on alias column. Here is as far as i got but its not working - it still brings non distinct records.

```
Location.where("calendar_account_id = ?", current_user.calendar_accounts.first).group(:id,:alias).order("alias ASC").distinct.group_by(&:category)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Location.select("DISTINCT(alias), *").where("calendar_account_id = ?", current_user.calendar_accounts.first).order("alias ASC").group_by(&:category)
```

or

```
Location.where("calendar_account_id = ?", current_user.calendar_accounts.first).group(:alias).order("alias ASC").group_by(&:category)
```